# How to insert value in existing list in a specific index by moving the existing value to next index using python

Tags: python, list, indexing, insert

I have list like below.

```
test = ['firstvalue', 'thirdvalue']
```

I want to insert the some values to the list.
secondvalue at index 1 and fourthvalue at index 3

so the output list looks like below

```
test = ['firstvalue', 'secondvalue', 'thirdvalue', 'fourthvalue']
```

I tried the below way but it doesn't work for me

```
print test.insert(1, "secondvalue")
```

Is there any alternate way to do this?

Comment: @ timgeb - I am editing my question

Comment: `insert` does not return the list, try `print(test)` after the `test.insert`

Comment: "it doesn't work for me", but what actually happens? You need to explain the actual vs expected outcome to be helpful.

Comment: @VPfB - Not working

Comment: @sushil you know, you can really drive people crazy with repeating "not working" as the explanation of the problem.

Comment: sorry its my fault... it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What worked? You might as well explain what you did to fix the problem for others who might be having the same problem.  This is equally if not worse than just saying "it didn't work".

Comment: `test.insert(1, "secondvalue")` Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The insert function does not return a value, but rather modifies the array used on it. Here's an example:

```
test = ['firstvalue', 'thirdvalue']
test.insert(1, "secondvalue")
print test
```

Comment: Can we add multiple values in single insert

Comment: @sushil no, you can't.

Comment: Thanks for the reply